# Aesthetics of Kable Extra and Rmardown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I am reproducing the following code in R to style my table

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

item<-c("question1.NATURALES" ,   "question2.NATURALES"   , "question3.NATURALES"   , "question4.NATURALES",   
  "question5.NATURALES"  ,  "question6.NATURALES"  ,  "question7.NATURALES"  ,  "question8.NATURALES"   ,
  "question9.NATURALES"    ,"question10.NATURALES")

key<-c("C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "D", "B", "A", "D", "C" )
A<-c(0 ,3 ,0, 1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0, 2 ,0)
B<-c(0, 0, 1 ,0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1 )


fa<-data.frame("item"=item,"key"=key, "A"=A,"B"=B)

fa %>%
  kbl(escape = FALSE,booktabs = TRUE,longtable=TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(fixed_thead = T,repeat_header_text = "continuaci\\'on",
        repeat_header_continued="contin\\'ua en la siguiente p\\'agina") %>%
  kable_paper(c("striped","condensed","scale_down","repeat_header"), 
              full_width = FALSE)


tmp<- data.frame(t(
  data.frame(t(select(fa, -item, -key))) %>% 
    mutate_all(function(i) cell_spec(i, color = ifelse(i == max(i), "green", "red")))
), row.names = NULL)

cbind(fa[1],fa[ 2], tmp) %>%
  kbl(escape = FALSE,booktabs = TRUE,longtable=TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(fixed_thead = T,repeat_header_text = "continuaci\\'on",
        repeat_header_continued="contin\\'ua en la siguiente p\\'agina") %>%
  kable_paper(c("striped","condensed","scale_down","repeat_header"), 
              full_width = FALSE)
```

But when printing the pdf the result is as follows

[image]

It doesn't show stylized or show the words of the page change but if I run it in the console I get the following

[image]

I would like to know what is happening because in the pdf it shows me in a less aesthetic way.

Of course, if you have any other advice, it's welcome.

Comment: I can't explain the difference between console and PDF output, but [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) explains that not all `kable_styling` options are available with `kable_paper`: " ... The only difference is that bootstrap_options (as discussed in the next section) is replaced with lightable_options at the same location with only two choices striped and hover available.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to print your table using Rmarkdown. I found that we can get the striped style in PDF by using `latex_options = "striped"` in `kable_styling()` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

item<-c("question1.NATURALES" ,   "question2.NATURALES"   , "question3.NATURALES"   , "question4.NATURALES",   
  "question5.NATURALES"  ,  "question6.NATURALES"  ,  "question7.NATURALES"  ,  "question8.NATURALES"   ,
  "question9.NATURALES"    ,"question10.NATURALES")

key<-c("C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "D", "B", "A", "D", "C" )
A<-c(0 ,3 ,0, 1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0, 2 ,0)
B<-c(0, 0, 1 ,0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1 )


fa<-data.frame("item"=item,"key"=key, "A"=A,"B"=B)

fa %>%
  kbl(escape = FALSE,booktabs = TRUE,longtable=TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(fixed_thead = T,
        repeat_header_text = "continuaci\\'on",
        repeat_header_continued="contin\\'ua en la siguiente p\\'agina",
        latex_options = "striped") %>%
  kable_paper(c("striped","condensed","scale_down","repeat_header"), 
              full_width = FALSE)


tmp<- data.frame(t(
  data.frame(t(select(fa, -item, -key))) %>% 
    mutate_all(function(i) cell_spec(i, color = ifelse(i == max(i), "green", "red")))
), row.names = NULL)

cbind(fa[1],fa[ 2], tmp) %>%
  kbl(escape = FALSE,booktabs = TRUE,longtable=TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(fixed_thead = T,
        repeat_header_text = "continuaci\\'on",
        repeat_header_continued="contin\\'ua en la siguiente p\\'agina", 
        latex_options = "striped") %>%
  kable_paper(c("striped","condensed","scale_down","repeat_header"), 
              full_width = FALSE)
```

The code results in the following two tables in PDF:

[image]

Comment: thanks, it's great, it improves the aesthetics

Comment: all of a sudden i started getting this error on the chuck Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': unused arguments (-item, -KEY)

Comment: I have just re-run the exactly same code that you provided in the example above in my computer, but I got no error and no warning. I also copy-paste-run it on https://rdrr.io/snippets/, again no error and no warning.

Comment: my mistake was touching the visual button for some reason this got out of control the code